# Poor _rotl performance under minGW

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I've got a program which is performance-reliant on the rotate-left instruction.

Under MSVC, it works fairly well, just define the _rotl() intrinsic as the target for rotate left.

Under GCC for Linux, it also works well. Here it is enough to define the equivalent software construction `rotl32(x,r) = ((x << r) | (x >> (32 - r)))` , the compiler is clever enough to recognize this is a 32-bits rotate left, and automatically replace it by its intrinsic equivalent (to be fair, MSVC is also able to make such detection).

Under MinGW, not so much. This is all the more intriguing as MinGW is using, at its core, GCC. MinGW can compile the windows intrinsic `_rotl`, but without apparently triggering the corresponding intrinsic. The software version seems also undetected, although to be fair, it is nonetheless faster than `_rotl`. The end result is a 10x reduction in performance, so it is definitely significant.

Note : GCC version of tested MinGW is 4.6.2

Comment: Can you post an example along with the assembly generated (using the `-S` and `-O2` options)?  My tests with MinGW 4.6.1 and 4.7.2 indicate that it will use a `rol` (or sometimes a `ror`) instruction to implement a call to an inline `rotl32()` function that simply returns the expression you gave -  as long as the arguments involved are `unsigned`.  This seems a sensible requirement since your expression has undefined behavior for negative values (and some non-negative values when a signed type is used).

Comment: However, the `_rotl()` 'intrinsic' is apparently implemented as a non-inline function call to a library function in MinGW.

Comment: all inputs are uint32_t

Comment: Note that while compilers for microcomputers used to be designed in a fashion that would always treat the given definition for `rotl32` as evaluating to either `x|0` or `x|x` (possibly chosen arbitrarily) in case `r` was 0, and it didn't matter which value was chosen since both would evaluate to `x`, such treatment is no longer fashionable.  It is instead necessary to replace the portion to the right of `|` with an alternative construct like `(x >> (31-r) >> 1)` or `(x >> ((-r) & 31))` so as to make the program safe for use with optimizing compilers, even though the latter forms are likely...

Comment: ...to be slower on many compilers and are harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you're stuck with the intrinsic on Windows, here's a way to do it using inline assembler on x86;

```c
uint32_t rotl32_2(uint32_t x, uint8_t r) {
  asm("roll %1,%0" : "+r" (x) : "c" (r));
  return x;
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu's gcc, but should work well on mingw.

Comment: Thanks, I'm typically shy of assembler code, due to lack of knowledge, but also portability issues. MinGW is only one target, not even the main one. Nonetheless, it's an interesting input. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Just include `intrin.h` header.

It is windows-specific header so if you are developing a cross-platform software do not forget to wrap it with a condition like that:

```c++
#ifdef _WIN32
# include <intrin.h>
#endif
```

### Benchmark

```
Run on (4 X 3310 MHz CPU s)
09/07/16 23:29:35
Benchmark                    Time           CPU Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------
BM_rotl/8                   19 ns         18 ns   37392923
BM_rotl/64                 156 ns        149 ns    4487151
BM_rotl/512               1148 ns       1144 ns     641022
BM_rotl/4k                9286 ns       9178 ns      74786
BM_rotl/32k              71575 ns      69535 ns       8974
BM_rotl/256k            583148 ns     577204 ns       1000
BM_rotl/2M             4769689 ns    4830999 ns        155
BM_rotl/8M            19997537 ns   18720120 ns         35
BM_rotl_intrin/8             6 ns          6 ns  112178768
BM_rotl_intrin/64           55 ns         53 ns   14022346
BM_rotl_intrin/512         431 ns        407 ns    1725827
BM_rotl_intrin/4k         3327 ns       3338 ns     224358
BM_rotl_intrin/32k       27093 ns      26596 ns      26395
BM_rotl_intrin/256k     217633 ns     214167 ns       3205
BM_rotl_intrin/2M      1885492 ns    1853925 ns        345
BM_rotl_intrin/8M      8015337 ns    7626716 ns         90
```

### Benchmark code

```c++
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#define MAKE_ROTL_BENCHMARK(name) \
  static void name(benchmark::State& state) { \
    auto arr = new uint32_t[state.range(0)]; \
    while (state.KeepRunning()) { \
      for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); ++i) { \
        arr[i] = _rotl(arr[i], 16); \
      } \
    } \
    delete [] arr; \
  } \
  /**/

MAKE_ROTL_BENCHMARK(BM_rotl)
#include <intrin.h>
MAKE_ROTL_BENCHMARK(BM_rotl_intrin)

#undef MAKE_ROTL_BENCHMARK

BENCHMARK(BM_rotl)->Range(8, 8<<20);
BENCHMARK(BM_rotl_intrin)->Range(8, 8<<20);

BENCHMARK_MAIN()
```