# Rotate left/right with number of moves using GCC assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, assembly, x86

I have the following code to calculate rotate left/right in Visual Studio assembly.

```
template<class T>
inline T rotr(T x, unsigned char moves){
    unsigned char temp;
    __asm{
        mov temp, CL
            mov CL, moves
            ror x, CL
            mov CL, temp
    };
    return x;
}
template<class T>
inline T rotl(T x, unsigned char moves){
    unsigned char temp;
    __asm{
        mov temp, CL
            mov CL, moves
            rol x, CL
            mov CL, temp
    };
    return x;
}
```

1- How can we write the equivalent asm code for gcc.

2- Is there a better way to write it in Visual Studio assembly?

Comment: VC++ has `_rotl`/`_rotr` (for `int`s) and `_rotl64`/`_rotr64` for `long long`) in the standard library.

Comment: Similarly, gcc (gas) x86 assembly has rol/ror (rotate and do not include carry), and rcl/rcr (rotate including carry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer here:

[Poor _rotl performance under minGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872197/poor-rotl-performance-under-mingw)

and rewritten my code to be:

```
template<class T> 
inline  T rotr(T x, uint8_t r) {
      asm("rorl %1,%0" : "+r" (x) : "c" (r));
      return x;
    }

template<class T> 
inline  T rotl(T x, uint8_t r) {
      asm("roll %1,%0" : "+r" (x) : "c" (r));
      return x;
    }
```

Thank you for the useful comments about _rotl/_rotr _rotl64/_rotr64 from  Jerry Coffin and  gnometorule